# Rofi Is Just A White Line

Tags: i3-window-manager

When ever I try to run rofi like this:

```
bindsym $mod+d exec rofi -show run -lines 3 -eh 2 -width 100 -padding 800 -opacity "85" -bw 0 -bc "$bg-color" -bg "$bg-color" -fg "$text-color" -hlbg "$bg-color" -hlfg "#9575cd" -font "System San Francisco Display 18"
```

it just appears as a white line in the middle of the screen.
When I use compton the line is transparent.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a smaller value for `padding`.

Depending on connected display `padding` may be too big. `padding` is the size of the margin between the outer border and the input field, on every side. Setting it to `800` means that `rofi` to put a margin of 800 pixel above *and* below the input field, as well as on the left and right side. So your display would need to be larger than 1600 pixel in any direction.

It looks like you are using an older version of `rofi` which does not check the available space beforehand. Newer versions of `rofi` will print a warnig if the configured parameters will not fit on your screen.